# Detect if a waypoint is reachable

Tags: javascript, jquery-waypoints

currently I try to find out a way to detect if a container can reach the offset which has been set via waypoints and how I am able to execute the same function (in the same scope) if the offset can't be reached.

One example would be if you have a lot of container in the page and define an offset of 50%. Now you have a container which is rather small and if you scroll to the bottom of the document the offset can't be reached, because the document is not long enough the container to pass the 50% offset.

Waypoints-Example:

```
$(".elements").waypoints(function(direction){
    /*do something*/
}, offset:"50%");
```

Is there any way to say something like this?

Pseudo-Code:

```
$(".elements").waypoints(function(direction){
    /*do something*/
}, offset:"50% XOR document-end");
```

So if the break point is reached it triggers at 50% or the document is scrolled to the end and then the same function is executed, but only by the last element.

kind regards and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve the problem by defining a custom function:

```
Waypoint.offsetAliases["myfunction"] = function() {...}
```

See

https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/blob/master/lib/jquery.waypoints.js#l157